# How to list files on the server with Ruby Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a folder with thousands of files and I would like to be able to view their contents via the webpage. 
I was wondering if its possible to list those files using Ruby Rails?

I get that with ruby I can potentially use the **Dir.glob("*.txt")** but I am not sure how that can be used on Rails.

It seems the only way with Rails is to create a DB but the problem with that is that I haven't been able to find a way to upload all these files to the DB.

All I find online are ways of creating/uploading single files to the DB.

If you can think of a better language/framework to accomplish this, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple. In your controller:

```
def index
  @files = Dir["/path/to/dir/*.txt"] #Array with files full_names
end
```

In your view:

```
<ul>
  <% @files.each do |file| %>
    <li><%=file%></li> 
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is similar to what I was trying except for the code in my view.
Now that I try it I get the following: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
That is from the code in my View.

Comment: You should use `Dir["/path/to/dir/*.txt"]` but replace "/path/to/dir/" to your actually dir.  Did you do that?

Comment: yeah I did that and no errors appeared in regards to the Controller, only for View.

Comment: Can you share your full controller and view with name?

Comment: checks_controller.rb

`class ChecksController < ApplicationController

  def checks
   @file = Dir["/home/jay/checksforrails/*.txt"]
  end
end`

checks.html.erb

`<h1>Checks page</h1>

<ul>
  <% @files.each do |file| %>
    <li><%=file%></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>`

Comment: In your controller change `@file` to `@files`.

Comment: `Dir` takes an absolute path or relative path.  Make sure the .txt files are reachable  from that path and there are actual txt files there.

Comment: sorry, I did have it set to `@files` but I had changed it and forgot to revert it. But the issue is still present.
As for the files actually being there, they are but they have a different extension, I used .txt as an example but obviously I changed it in my code.

Comment: Alright so I moved it to the index.html.erb view and it works but is being show in the home page. Not sure if my route to the checks page is wrong. I can reach the checks page and view whatever is defined so I don't know what could be wrong

Comment: Thank you all, I simply recreated my checks controller with an index view and put everything together and it worked!
Now to find out how to make the files clickable(links)...